# PHPUNIT gives COLOR_AUTO undefined class constant

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, config

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'COLOR_AUTO' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend-doctrine\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php on line 584

Call Stack:
    0.0018     209368   1. {main}() C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:0
    0.0342     768592   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() 

C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:500
    0.0342     771992   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() 

C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:243
    0.0342     772048   4. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() 

C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:138
    0.0342     773256   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() 

C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:248
    0.2740    2873064   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getPHPUnitConfiguration()

C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:601
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error because the phpunit version installed globally on my system (9) was newer than the version in my project (6). I solved this by running PHP unit from the vendor directory as mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1724#issuecomment-105277125).

Answer (score 0):

Check where is COLOR_AUTO class file and include it in Configuration.php file

Comment: It is in the vendor map, being installed by composer. version PHPUNIT 5.5.3
So i cannot include it in the file because it gets overriden with an update.

Answer (score 0):

It was generated by an old version of PHPSTORM that i was using, bought a new version and it works.